# Получить значения из составного типа

Tags: postgresql

Есть тип:

```
   CREATE TYPE ComprositiontTransfer AS (
        Id BIGINT,
        Name CHARACTER VARYING,
        COUNT BIGINT,
        Price NUMERIC,
        IdExport CHARACTER VARYING,  
        IdImport CHARACTER VARYING
    );
```

В таблице:

```
CREATE TABLE "Transfer" (
    "Id" serial NOT NULL,
    "Date" TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME zone NOT NULL,
    "OrgPostav" CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
    "NameSklad" CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
    "Сomposition" ComprositiontTransfer[] NOT NULL,
    "Operator" CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
    "Total" NUMERIC,
    "Changed" BOOLEAN,
    "OneCid" CHARACTER VARYING,
    CONSTRAINT Transfer_pk PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
) WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Как мне к примеру, получить все транспортировки по указанному сотруднику? (Поле IdExport в составном типе)

Comment: Приведите пример для двух каких-нибудь строчек данных. А нерелевантные поля (кроме разве что первичного ключа) лучше вообще выкинуть, для вопроса это лишний объём.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать это можно вот так:

```
 SELECT id,  u  FROM "Transfer", unnest("Transfer"."Сomposition") u WHERE u.IdExport = '25' ;
```

Comment: А где ваше "по сотруднику"? Вопрос решительно не стыкуется с ответом.

Comment: u.IdExport - это поле и есть его ID. Так я получил id всех записей в расходах

Comment: А, окей. Вот для этого я и просил привести пример. Ответ сойдёт за пример.

Comment: Благодарю вас, за отклик.